# design time usercontrols - I can't see anything!

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

newbie question, please forgive...

I'm developing a Wpf UserControl that will eventually be bound to a business object.  The usercontrol is little more than a series of laid out TextBlocks, and perhaps (later) an image or two.

As I'm laying out the usercontrol, I can put dummy text into all the TextBlocks so I can see what the usercontrol will look like, but as soon as I change the text property to contain the Binding information:

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,12.8,42,0" Name="lblLastName" 
       FontSize="8" Height="19" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=LastName}"/>
```

Then I can no longer see the textbox, or any "placeholder" text.  This makes it very difficult to adjust the location and sizes of all the controls on the UserControl.  In WinFormas programming, you could set binding information independently of the Text property, so you could at least see the Placeholder text during design time development.  It's going to be pretty hard to visually arrange a bunch of invisible TextBlocks!  What's the standard solution for this?

Comment: It's not a reply to your question, but in general I would _strongly_ recommend against using visual XAML designer, and drag'n'drop XAML design in general, and work with markup directly. You will only get proper reflowing/resizing layouts if you do that, just as is the case in HTML. Learn to work with `StackPanel` and `Grid`, and forget visually aligning controls to match as a bad dream...

Comment: Agree with Pavel 100%; initially when making the shift from WinForms to XAML I also tried to use the visual designer to design my windows. It is much slower than writing the markup by hand and you will never get quite what you want. Spend the time becoming intimately familiar with XAML, layout panels, and their various attached properties, and it will pay off dividends in UI design.

Comment: Think of the designer as a way to quickly zoom to a particular place in the XAML.  It's nothing like the comprehensive tool that the WinForms designer is.

Comment: Understood-  thanks for the advice.  I'm all for developing directly in XAML, but it seems a bit "stone age" to have to run my program to see what my form is going to look like. I guess the design time mock objects are the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `Background` of the `TextBlock` to something visible enough if it's the same color as the visuals behind it, and set `HorizontalAlignment` to "Stretch". This way it will fill the available width. That, or set the `MinWidth` to an explicit number. No text, but it will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used design time mock objects to get a good preview of what everything will look like:

[Viewing Design Time Data in Visual Studio 2008 Cider Designer in WPF and Silverlight Projects](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/viewing-design-time-data-in-visual-studio-2008-cider-designer-in-wpf-and-silverlight-projects/)